# Relocated for an internship, still no work permit

Tags: internship, legal, relocation, international

I am a student, and I recently accepted an offer to do an internship in a foreign subsidiary of a big company A.

I was due to start some time ago, and was given help (by a third actor B, a company which company A assigned to me) with the logistics and legal issues.

B has secured my accommodation (which I am to pay for shortly), and obtained a temporary residency permit for me well before my start date. I was told (by B) to relocate a few days before my intended start date, which I did. I was not involved in the process, apart from providing my passport.

Company B has not, however, as of now, succeeded in obtaining my work permit. Thus, I'm not able to work, nor I know the approximate date I will be able to work.

As I won't receive any money from A until well after my start date, I will shortly be lacking funds to support myself and pay for my accommodation. 
Therefore, I'm planning to cut my losses, abandon this internship, go back to my home country and find another job, so I can pay for the reserved accommodation.

1. Can I face any legal repercussions for this? If no, is this a smart thing to do? (i.e. will it get me blacklisted or hurt me in other ways?)
2. Do I have any way of obtaining any part of the accommodation support/relocation bonus, so I can pay for my futile stay in the country?
3. In the case I get my work permit, say, tomorrow, and start working after my intended start date: am I still obliged to work for the intended duration of the internship, or I can work only until the intended end date?

Comment: I expect that this will be closed because it is a purely legal question that will depend on the countries involved and the specifics of the agreements you signed.  It is possible that it would be on topic over on the law stack but you may be better off talking to a lawyer.

Comment: Have you tried speaking to A and B (but mostly A)? They are probably in a better position to tell you how long things might still take, and what the plan is (or should be) from here, whether the contract will be pushed forward or shortened, and maybe even make a financial arrangement that will enable you to stay until it's sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Someone somewhere made a mistake.

Call your manager at A and your contact person at B and explain the problem - both that you cannot work, and that this is going to be expensive for you.

Use the telephone rather than email.  It may take several attempts to reach the right people, but phone calls are usually more effective than emails for this sort of situation.  (For that matter, if B's office is near by, visit them in person.)

**Stick solely to the facts** - you do not have a permit to work, and without work you cannot pay for the housing.  Do not make assumptions and do not assign blame.  You don't know why B failed to get the permit to you.

**This mess isn't going to fix itself.**.  Get on the phone and call people.

With luck, you'll still have a great internship at A and you'll have learned a thing or two about solving this sort of mix up.